# how to pass game center data between activities?

Tags: android

Well, I'm implementing the new game center in android and there is a concept that i don't understand.

I have a class which extends BaseGameActivity (https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init), so it's the one who manages achievements, leaderboards, Google + sign in, etc.
I need another class to be able to access game center data from that activity (unlock achievements, leaderboards, etc), but this class is not called from the extending BaseGameActivity class.

How can they communicate?

The structure is like this (meaning "->" that it starts other activity)

A (extends BaseGameActivity) -> B -> C (needs game center communication with A)

I have read the google's example (TypeANumber) but it uses a Listener to communicate, that's easy when the class you need to communicate with is the one which you are starting, but it's not as easy with my structure.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: haven't looked at the documents yet but can you put the data you need as an Extra in an `Intent`?

Comment: Well, one thing you could try doing is instead of extending the BaseGameActivity is looking at how they implement it and then put that GamesCient at the root level of your Application. It looks like that for the authentication piece the GamesClient would require an activity to be up, but I am sure you could find a way to initialize the games client for the global application from your initial activity pretty easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I think is you have 3 choices:

1. Create a GamesClient for each Activity that needs it, but you have to call connect() for each activity, and it takes time. After the first connection, the other ones are much faster (a few hundred milliseconds)
2. Create your own Application class and use it as a context for the GamesClient.Builder, and store your GamesClient object in your Application class. I've tested it, and it works. Now, I know it's discouraged to do that (because it breaks the Android philosophy) but it seems a lot of people prefer to create their own application class and store data into it instead of bundling data and passing them from one activity to another. Its main advantage is that you don't have to modify a lot of thing to make it work in your case (and in mine).
3. Use Fragment classes instead of Activity classes and use a main Activity which owns the GamesClient object (in that case, your class C would be able to communicate with class A). Like in the example you're mentioning, there's only one Activity which inherits from Google example's BaseGameActivity (which contains the GamesClient instance), and the rest is just Fragment classes (each Fragment being a screen).

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way to share a GamesClient between the multiple screens in a game is use Fragments, which I tried to illustrate in the TypeANumber sample.

That said, if you still want to have multiple Activities, each activity must manage *its own* GamesClient object, because a GamesClient is tied to a specific Activity. Therefore, if you're using the sample code, then each Activity would have to derive from BaseGameActivity, and each of them would get onSignInSucceeded(). In each of them, you can use getGamesClient() to obtain the GamesClient object for *that* Activity.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, that's what i finally did. Maybe next time i will try to implement Fragments

Comment: Unfortunately it's not always feasible to have a single Activity with Fragments. Nor indeed to extend a base class; each third party library seems to assume you can just extend their base class, but Java has single inheritance and I may well want to use different libraries at once. I really wish there was an application-scoped lifecycle for these sort of cases.

Answer (score 0):

How about encapsulating all the data that needs to be shared into a singleton object, e.g.

```
class SharedData {
    public String aString;
    public double aDouble;
    // etc
    public static SharedData globalInstance = new SharedData();
}
```

and then all parts of your app can access via SharedData.globalInstance.

Comment: Singletons are an antipattern. I'd discourage this. Better to use the application object if your going down this route rather than defining a shared data singleton

Comment: @0909EM I'm not sure what you mean by an antipattern?  The [documentation for the application object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) even mentions singletons.  In any case, I agree that using the application object achieves the same goal.

Comment: Sorry to point you at wikipedia (its either the very best or very worst of resources) http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern I've had mixed experiences with Singletons sometimes v useful and sometimes a sod to test... just wanted to point out that singletons are sometimes considered an anti pattern

Answer (score 0):

Just ideas... I haven't looked at the code so treat this with a pince of salt..

Can you encapsulate inside a parcel able/serializable and then use set/getparceable in each activity that needs it? I'd recommend passing an interface down, but not sure how easy that'd be without looking at code

Alternatively can you wrap the game client logic in a service that you can interact with from each activity?

Comment: No, it was not Serializable or Parcelable. What i was trying to achieve was to login just once, and try to send the data to the activity where i logged in.
The only solution is to use fragments.